# How to make people to see each other on the website through web camera?

Tags: html, flash, camera

I want to run a website where people could see each other through web camera. I can't find anything in google, so, can you give me any suggestions or link to tutorial?
Thanks

Comment: @Donator, there are a lot of pieces necessary to design that sort of application - do you have a more specific question?

Comment: What do I need to learn? What language to start it?

Comment: Do you want to build www.chatroulette.com?

Comment: you will definitely need an own server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Action Script 3 + Flash Media Server or opensource Red5 server 
http://osflash.org/red5

Answer (score 3):

Would like to try something hot ?

[Silverlight 4](http://silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight-4-beta/) (now in Beta) seems to have support for microphone&webcam. You will need to create server side for it as well. Probably some kind of user management and contact list. There will be significant bandwidth if you get lot of users, so the server side should created be scalable to multiple machines. Maybe [Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/) cloud ? With any platform you choose it will take lot of effort.

Answer (score 2):

I belive that you did not undestand that this think you ask, if you going to build it its takes months of design and developing.

if you search for "web chat webcam" you maybe see why I say that.

For example this http://www.ivideochat.com/ site have developed a program for that reason. See how complicate it is, how many think have.

Also you did not say, what platform you using, what is your server that going to split the video channels and send them all over the other, are you going to use it for one to one, or all to all, are you going to build it on asp.net ? on linux, on flash, on what ?

Some times small thinks in words, are too huge in developing.

So for me you must define a lot of thinks and then maybe you can see if you can do that.
**1**.Media stream server ?  example http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/
**2**.Developing platform.
**3**.Number of possible users.
**4**.The way they goint o interact each other.
**5**.All of them need to have camera ?
**6**.What about bad users (that show bad thinks) ?
**7**.Do they going to chat also ?

Think about all that first, then maybe is more clear to you what you going to get.

Answer (score 2):

> An adsl connection 12$,
>  a computer
>   320$,
>  as3 documentacion about [camera
>   class](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Camera.html) priceless

Comment: .. and a server to bounce the chat off?

Comment: ADSL is going to cost more than $12, unless you are going to write it finish in a month.

Answer (score 0):

Architecturally, you need a server to relay the video/audio to both parties, since they cannot connect directly.

You need a Silverlight or Flash 'movie' running in the browser, which you have written, and you need a server to do the relaying.

Its relatively straightforward using **Haxe**.

[Haxe](http://haxe.org) is a Free language for creating both Flash 'movies' and server applications (and more; read their homepage).

One of the Haxe-related servers that is available for Free is [HaxeVideo](http://code.google.com/p/haxevideo/) - literally a video server that (among other things) supports live streaming from clients.  Run HaxeVideo on a server and you can easily make Flash clients (written in the Haxe language naturally) do video chat.

There are several sites that do precisely this e.g. [Reel Portal](http://www.reelportal.com/) and [DoVisio](http://www.dovisio.com/)

If you anticipate a very high volume you can turn to $$$ servers such as [Wowza](http://www.wowzamedia.com/) or [Flash Media Server (FMS)](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/), or you can simply add peering support to HaxeVideo.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is to hire a developer or two who know how to build web-applications involving real-time audio & video capabilities in Flex/Silverlight.